# Automatic row selection in NatTable

Tags: eclipse, selection, nattable

I would like to programmatically select certain rows in a `NatTable`

There is some sample code in the [NatTable example program](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/nattable/releases/1.1.0/NatTableExamples-1.1.0.jar) (under Classic Examples -> Selection -> Get and set selected objects) which uses an ISelectionProvider (in that case an org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.nattable.selection.RowSelectionProvider).

```
ISelectionProvider selectionProvider = new RowSelectionProvider(gridLayer.getBodyLayer().getSelectionLayer(), bodyDataProvider, false);
selectionProvider.setSelection(new StructuredSelection(new Person[] { homer, smithers, nelson }));
```

From another source I found a simpler way to select rows:

```
natTable.doCommand(new SelectRowsCommand(ILayer layer, int columnPosition, int rowPosition, boolean withShiftMask, boolean withControlMask));
```

Is there any reason not to use the second approach?

Answer (score 0):

As you already mentioned, the first approach is using ISelectionProvider which is typically used to share selections between parts in an Eclipse application.

The second approach is the NatTable default. Internally the selection provider does the same. So if you only care about selecting programmatically, it is fine to use it without the selection provider.